# What is the best practice to ensure resume of previously fetched Core Data objects after relaunching application?

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data

I want to achieve "resume" feature in my app. After relaunching an app I want to fetch managed objects fetched at a last app termination. What is the best practice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't make this more complicated than it has to be.

Since Core Data automatically saves the state of the entire object graph, executing a fetch using the same predicate as in the previous run will return the same exact set of managed objects as in the previous run.

Comment: So should I archive an predicate object (or predicate string)?

Comment: You can if it changes during runtime. Otherwise, predicate instances are not unique so if you recreate the predicate's content you will get the same results from the fetch.

Comment: Yes it changes. Okay I'll archive a predicate string. Thank for your advice.